# Why os.getppid() and multiprocessing.parent_process().pid got different result using multiprocessing in airflow 2.x?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I found that when using airflow, using multiprocessing causes an assert error. I solved my error ( [this discussion](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/14896) and [this discussion](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1709) ). but I was curious about how process actually works in airflow job, so I ran the code.

```
def process_function(i):
    parent_process = multiprocessing.parent_process().pid
    parent_process_daemon = (
        multiprocessing.parent_process().daemon
        if multiprocessing.parent_process() is not None
        else None
    )
    current_process = multiprocessing.current_process().pid
    is_daemon = multiprocessing.current_process().daemon
    result = (
        f"{i}th task : "
        + "partent_process : "
        + str(parent_process)
        + " is daemon : "
        + str(parent_process_daemon)
        + " current_process : "
        + str(current_process)
        + " is daemon : "
        + str(is_daemon)
    )
    time.sleep(3)
    return result


def mp(run_n: int):
    print(f"start checking multiprocessing pid task")
    print("[1] check pid using os modlue")
    print(f"parent process : {os.getppid()} current process : {os.getpid()}")
    print("[2] check pid using multiprocessingmodlue")
    print(
        f"parent process : {multiprocessing.parent_process().pid if multiprocessing.parent_process() is not None else None} is daemon? : {multiprocessing.parent_process().daemon if multiprocessing.parent_process() is not None else None} process : {multiprocessing.current_process().pid} is daemon? : {multiprocessing.current_process().daemon}"
    )

    results = []
    print(f"start job")
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as process_executor:
        for pp_res in process_executor.map(process_function, [i for i in range(run_n)]):
            results.append(pp_res)
    print(f"job done")
    for c in results:
        print(c)
...

with models.DAG(
    dag_id="daemon_test",
    description="daemon_test",
    schedule_interval="0 * * * *",
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
   test_job = PythonOperator(
        task_id="test_job ",
        python_callable=mp,
        op_kwargs={
            "run_n": 5,
        },
    )
```

and result

```
{standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 67070 to run task
...
start checking multiprocessing pid task
[1] check pid using os modlue
parent process : 67069 current process : 67070

[2] check pid using multiprocessing modlue
parent process : None is daemon? : None process : 67070 is daemon? : True
...
0th task : partent_process : 67070 is daemon : False current_process : 67071 is daemon : True
1th task : partent_process : 67070 is daemon : False current_process : 67072 is daemon : True
2th task : partent_process : 67070 is daemon : False current_process : 67073 is daemon : True
3th task : partent_process : 67070 is daemon : False current_process : 67074 is daemon : True
4th task : partent_process : 67070 is daemon : False current_process : 67071 is daemon : True
```

**Even though the pid value can be changed, I don't think that None value can come out. Does anyone know the reason for this?**

Comment: I got `PYTHONOPTIMIZE = 1` airflow env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; a PID (or a parent PID) can't be `None`.

`multiprocessing.parent_process()` returns the value of the (multiprocessing-child-)internal global `multiprocessing.process._parent_process`.

That global is only set [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ad817cd5c44416da3752ebf9baf16d650703275c/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L290-L336) in the subprocesses **only** when the process is spawned as a `multiprocessing` child.

`os.getppid()`, on the other hand, just calls the OS function to get the parent PID, be it a multiprocessing parent or something else.

Comment: thx for your answer! But I still didn't understand the change of daemon state before and after ProcessPoolExecutor work. Could you give me a little more help?

Comment: @London_-_ Please see [the docs for `mp.Process.daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon).